# Sliding down label depending on time difference

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have two time fields, `timeFrom` and `timeTo`. What I want to do is get a label sliding down if the time difference is equal or greater than 2. But I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#timeTo").change(function()) {
        var timeTo = $("#timeTo").val();
        var timeFrom = $("#timeFrom").val();
        var diff = timeTo - timeFrom;
        if (diff >= 2){
            $("#cost_label").slideDown();
        }
        else{
             $("#cost_label").slideUp();
        }
    });
    $("#cost_label").hide();
    $("#timeTo").trigger("change");
});
```

Comment: you have an extra paren after function(), maybe that is part of the problem

Comment: always check the dev console for errors, when you have syntax mistakes it will tell you.

Comment: oh god. haha, well regardless. my label still won't appear :/

Comment: also, looks like #cost_label is hidden, so you wont see it sliding anyway.

Comment: Try removing $("#cost_label").hide(); first, then check if the labels appears and slideUp/Down

Comment: I've always put $("label").hide(); down there and its worked. But i removed it like you guys said, but still no luck :/

Comment: So, i can whole heartedly tell you it's nothing to do with the hide. It's not getting diff >= 2. Even though the timeTo and timeFrom fields are both <input type="time"> fields. Hmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#timeTo").on('input', function () {
        var timeTo = $("#timeTo").val();
        var timeFrom = $("#timeFrom").val();
        var diff = parseFloat(timeTo) - parseFloat(timeFrom);
        alert(diff);
        if (diff >= 2) {
            $("#cost_label").slideDown({
                complete: function () {
                    $("#cost_label").hide();
                }
            });
        } else {
            $("#cost_label").slideUp({
                complete: function () {
                    $("#cost_label").hide();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

1. Your label is to hide when the animation completes so it doesn't hide immediately
2. Strings read as integers, because you can't subtract Strings
3. `on('input')` instead of `on(change)`, this is the right way to detect textfield changes
4. Removed parenthesis after anonymous function declaration, that was a syntax error ;)

You can always debug your problems and use logic to fix these issues.

[<kbd>Somewhat-working Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/bvjZE/7/)

Comment: i did it this way, the label stays visible until i change the timeFrom time, it goes invisible, then doesn't re appear at all. Even when the time difference is more than 2 hours.

Comment: yup that's the general idea. I tweaked it a little to do what i want it to. Thank you so much

Comment: Since you're here already, is there anyway to return diff? so i can use it on my php page?

Comment: @AnujHari What do you mean by that, exactly?

Comment: like for example, i need to use the time difference, to calculate a price. Is there an easy way to return diff from the javascript so i can use it in my PHP page

Comment: @AnujHari Yes, you could do something like `window.location.href = "myphpfile.php?time=" + diff;`

Answer (score 0):

You may not need the `+` to typecast values and may not need to `Math.abs` if you're using `type="number"` inputs with sensible min/max limits.
The `'keyup'` event will fire when a key goes from down to up position, so you will not need to unfocus (click or tab away from) the input box. You can also use `'keydown'` too, if you're too eager to wait, and don't mind events that fire every 14 milliseconds when the user falls asleep on the keyboard.
Use the $.on instead of the event-named methods so that you can listen for multiple events (as a space separated list) and listen for the event on both inputs (selectors need comma separated list).

```
$(function(){
    $('#cost_label').hide();
    $('#timeFrom,#timeTo').on('keyup change', timeChange);
    function timeChange(){
        var from = +$('#timeFrom').val();
        var to = +$('#timeTo').val();
        if(Math.abs(to - from) >= 2)
            $('#cost_label').slideDown();
        else $('#cost_label').slideUp();
    }
    timeChange();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LDB5X/  using `input type="text"`

http://jsfiddle.net/6M5V6/  using `input type="number"` (might not work in all browsers)

What is this 'input' event? I can't find it in the jquery docs